# Image exceeds row height

Tags: html, css

Hello i have a problem in insert an image. The Image height exceeds the row height of its parents.

```
<div class="contact">
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjk0sG6ibLKAhWEcI4KHYsMDTkQjB0IBg&url=http%3A%2F%2Flogos.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FFile%3ALogo_pln.jpg&psig=AFQjCNHf9civftbBawMR-5hGhERmmUzQBA&ust=1453162264247391" class="img-contact">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="footer shadow" align="center">
        &copy; Copyright 2015 UPT SULSELRABAR
    </div>
```

And The CSS below:

```
.contact{
padding:20px;
background-color:White;
height:;
}

.img-contact{
width:100%;
}

.footer{
position:bottom;
background-color:grey;
padding:20px 10px;
font-weight:bold;
}

.footer.shadow{
box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 6px -4px DimGray;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 6px -4px DimGray;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 6px -4px DimGray;
-o-box-shadow: inset 0px 8px 6px -4px DimGray;
}
```

How to make the row heights automatically adjust according to the child heights

Comment: The CSS you posted is not valid. `height:;` - there is something missing.

Answer (score 0):

You had some missing and unnecessary CSS/HTML in your code, so I've provided a working demo using the minimum to achieve this effect

```css
.contact {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: White;
  height: 100px;
}
.img-contact {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact">
  <img src="http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/logopedia/images/f/fc/Logo_pln.jpg" class="img-contact">
</div>
```

Just adjust the height in `.contact { }` to whatever height you would like. The child element (`.img-contact`) is set to `height: 100%` which will make it expand/contract to the parent element's height, and the `width: auto` is to maintain the image's aspect ratio.

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap column classes should only be the immediate children of a `.row` element. Review Bootstrap's grid documentation here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Fixing your html to include row elements should ensure the height of rows expand to accommodate the height of child columns. You'll also need to fix your invalid css.

Here's and example of what I think you're trying to achieve:

```
<div class="contact">
  <div class="row"><!-- row element -->
    <div class="col-md-12"><!-- column element, child of row -->
      <img src="#">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```